# Run php server through shell_exec and save its output to variable

Tags: php, terminal, server, shell-exec

When I try to run `shell_exec("php -S localhost:8000")`, it runs the server but it freezes the terminal.

I tried running `$result = shell_exec('php -S localhost:8000 -t public/ &> /dev/null 2>&1')` but it doesn't store the output to the variable.

The idea is so that I can customize the output message once server successfully boots up.

Comment: shell_exec("php -S localhost:8000 &") ?

Comment: @TomMillard sorry, but it isn't working either...